# Closure of question with legal tag

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I very recently asked a [question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/what-are-my-legal-rights-against-an-overfeeding-neighbour) about my legal options regarding a specific situation about my cat. The question is relatively promptly closed.

The reason I carry this here is that I believe this question does not carry the necessary conditions for closure.

- The question is strictly about a pet, not about wildlife.
- It is not an emergency situation. We close questions where people ask help in emergency situations because our advice here cannot replace vet consultancy and the time frame an answer is useful is quite limited. However, this question can be answered even a year later and the answer would still be useful.
- The question uses an already existing tag: `legal`

There might be some legitimate concerns to close this question.

- There is a better SE site to handle it.
- The question might be about a too specific situation, making an answer useful only to me.

While I agree that these concerns make sense, they are not addressed in the help pages. I also don't see how closing this particular question helps the site. Again, the main reason we close questions that require emergency help is to prevent people giving misleading advice in an urgent situation where they cannot access to all necessary information. This does not apply here.

My questions are:

- Why exactly this question is closed?
- Are the reasons for closure explicitly stated in the help pages?
- If they are not in the help pages, should we update them?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification: just like for “feature requests”, it’s customary on Meta to [use votes to express agreement/disagreement](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) with posts tagged “discussion”. (So not voting on the quality of the post.)

Answer (score 3):

The tag help states

> For questions related to laws, ordinances, rules, or regulations governing the behavior of pets and their handlers in public places.

For me, that would for example include leash laws or vaccinations, in short, what affects the pet directly. Also I would expect all legal questions to be reasonably generic. (“Can I be held responsible if my dog jumps on someone and damages their clothes?”)

Your post is asking about very specific legal actions against another person, pondering various options, thus  effectively asking for legal advice, not pet care advice. That makes it in my opinion off topic for Pets SE.

Just because there’s a certain tag doesn’t mean all posts that can be tagged with it are automatically within the site’s scope.

Comment: I don't think my questions falls out of tag definition, and I don't know why we should be expecting legal questions to be generic.

Comment: … because we are not lawyers?

Comment: Feel free to post another answer explaining why you consider it within our scope. That’s how community consensus is achieved.

Comment: I think my question explains my standing point, so there is no need at this moment to post an answer.

Comment: I know you _think_ the question is about a pet, @C.Koca, but from an outside/objective position (not one affected by the situation), the question is about people instead. You're asking for a legal route to change the behavior of another human, with the pet itself incidental to the issue. For that, and other reasons, this question is better suited to Law.SE